# Can I store a response object In a hashtable?

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have started writing a node application and I want to store the `request` and `response` objects In a hashtable. For the hashtable I am using `jshashtable`. When I store the `request` and `response` objects in the hashtable and fetch them later, I get a `Object.keys called on non-object` error when trying to use `response`, whether that be `writeHead()` or simply just printing with `console.log()`. However `typeof` returns `object` for `response`, so it appears that `response` is being manipulated when it's being stored in `jshashtable`. On the `jshashtable` website the author writes " 'Objects' here is used loosely to mean any JavaScript object or value. ", so It appears like I should be able to store any javascript object including the `response` object.

`jshashtable` can be installed with `npm install jshashtable`.

Here is some code that replicates the issue.

```
var Hashtable = require('jshashtable');
var crypto = require('crypto');
var table = new Hashtable();
var http = require('http');
var fs = require("fs");

var home = fs.readFileSync('/some/random/html/home.html');

http.createServer(function(req, res) {  
   crypto.randomBytes(8, function(ex, buf) {
   if (ex) throw ex;
     var userID = buf.toString('hex');

     var state = {
       "req": req,
       "res": res
     }

     table.put(userID, state);

     var message = {
       "httpCode": 200,
       "humanCode": "OK",
       "contentType": "text/html",
       "data": home
     };

     dataOut(userID, message, function(err, rtrn) {

     });
   });
}).listen(80);

function dataOut(userID, message, callback) {
    if(typeof callback === 'function') {

      var state;

      state = table.get(userID);
      if(state === null) {
        console.log("Can't get value");
        callback("Can't get value from key.", null);
      }

      if(typeof state.res === 'object') {
        console.log('This is an object');
      }

      //console.log(state.res);

      state.res.writeHead(message.httpCode, message.humanCode, message.contentType);
      state.res.write(message.data);
      state.res.end();
    }
  }
```

So why can't I use `request` and `response` after storing them In `jshashtable`?

Comment: You would call `JSON.parse()` on a string, not an actual Javascript object, which is what it looks like you're doing.

Comment: Yea I know but If it's a object, I shouldn't be getting `Objects.keys called on non object`,  so I assumed It was a string.

Comment: why are u using an hash table?

Comment: I'm using a hash table because I abstracted away the `https` code from the rest of the application. I don't want to just pass `req` and `res` into the business logic. The business logic acts on `userID`'s which the `https` code use's to look up the corresponding `req` and `res` values, I wanted to use the hash table to do the lookups.

Comment: @2trill2spill `userID` is a string right?

Comment: Yea `userID` is a string, you can see how it's created above. I use `userID` as the key for the hashtable.

Comment: ditch the janky hashtable and just use an object that doesn't have any surprises -$0.02...

Comment: @dandavis how would you store that object instead of a hashtable?

Comment: @dandavis: "janky" is a little harsh. I'd be surprised if jshashtable is doing anything wrong here.

Comment: I can't replicate this. jshashtable returns the object just fine. Are you sure `userID` is the same in the `put` and `get` calls?

Comment: I just checked and `userID` is the same for both the `put` and `get` call's.

Comment: The only error I encounter is on the `state.res.writeHead...` on line 51. Commenting that out, works fine and I can use the response object. 

The error with `res.writeHead` is how you pass arguments. It should be `res.writeHead(status, {header_Name: header_value, another_header: another_value})`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The only error I encounter is on the `state.res.writeHead...` on line 51. Commenting that out, works fine and I can use the response object. The error with `res.writeHead` is how you pass arguments. It should be `res.writeHead(status, {header_Name: header_value, another_header: another_value})`